# How to call a separate function file in swift 4

Tags: swift, function, call

I am used to working with Matlab and am struggling to work out how to do some of the same things in swift.

In Matlab, I can create a function in a separate file and save it (in the same directory) as function1.m

and in my second function "function2.m" I can simply call the function with 
function1(*Input arguments*) and it calls this separate file within "function 2".

is there any way to save just a function file in swift and call it in a separate playground or project. I am aware of how to call a function from within the same file in swift, however, if this function is written in a separate file, is there any way to call it, without having to explicitly copy/rewrite the function in the new file.

I have a file saved in the same directory that is called Fibonacci.swift which just contains a function for calculating the Fibonacci series, the function is called fibonacci and within that file i can call it simply by fibonacci(until: Int)

i have tried calling this fibonacci function from a separate file the same way with;
fibonacci (until: Int)
and also tried
Import Fibonacci.swift but this was more of a "I dont know what i'm doing" attempt

neither of the above attempts worked, so any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers 
- HB

Comment: What have you tried so far? Update your question with details.

Comment: Harry, you didn't even try. I just googled "swift playground multiple files", here's the third result: http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/swift-playground-tip-using-external-code-files/

Comment: Thanks Alexander, im still new to the whole stackoverflow world so apologies for that. i wasn't getting any info on "calling external swift functions" clearly i didn't have the correct key words.
Cheers for the help

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function needed to be public:

```
public func fibonacci(until: Int) {
    // Do something
}
```